# Result of bitwise AND appears to be 0, but isn't

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I've got the following situation:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int first = 0x08;

  printf("%d\n", first & 0b10);
  printf("%d\n", first & 0b10 == 0);

  if (first & 0b10 == 0) {
    printf("SET");
  } else {
    printf("NOT");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Two `0`s print out, followed by `NOT`. What is happening here? It seems to be that `first & 0b01` is zero, so should pass the condition.

Comment: Precedence rules: `first & 0b10 == 0` should be `(first & 0b10) == 0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue of operator precedence.

The bitwise AND operator `&` has lower precedence than the equality operator `==`.  So this:

```
first & 0b10 == 0
```

Is the same as:

```
first & (0b10 == 0)
```

Which is not what you want.  It compares `0b10` for equality with 0, which is false.  Then `first & 0` is evaluated which is 0.

Add parenthesis to get the desired behavior:

```
(first & 0b10) == 0
```

Comment: I always find it non-intuitive (and I see many similar mistakes). I wonder what is the reason behind making bitwise operator lower precedence than the comparison... These should be *on par* with arithmetic ops if you ask me.

Comment: @EugeneSh.The only reason I can think of is grouping them with the logical AND and OR operators, but even then `^`, `&`, `|`, `&&`, and `||` are all at their own precedence levels, meanwhile `!` and `~` are above the arithmetic operators.

Comment: Dennis Ritchie on the relative precedence of `&` and `==`: https://www.lysator.liu.se/c/dmr-on-or.html

Answer (score 2):

This is called [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

```
first & 0b10 == 0
```

First evaluated:

```
0b10 == 0  // which is false ==> 0
```

Then

```
first & 0  // which is also 0
```

To get the result you expect use parenthesis to force the order of evaluation:

```
(first & 0b10) == 0  // this will true ==> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

because == has higher precedence than &.

Here is the reference: [Operator Precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)